# Ajax Call With CodeIgniter Using Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I am using a simple POST to one of my controllers using Ajax, however in my in development tools it seems to never be able to find the controller. I get the error

```
POST http:// localhost:8888/time.php/checkit 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm not sure if this has something to do with the routes of CodeIgniter or the `.htaccess` file.

My Ajax call looks like:

```
  $("#submittodo").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'time.php/checkit',
          type: "POST",
          data: {name: $(this).val()},
          success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: can you visit http:// localhost:8888/time.php/checkit in your browser?  for code igniter that looks like a really strange url.  are you trying to hit /time/checkit   ?  could you elaborate on whats going wrong here?  not much to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo need to include base_url() on your url:

```
$("#submittodo").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>time.php/checkit',
      type: "POST",
      data: {name: $(this).val()},
      success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Also, check your config file, if you have $config['csrf_protection'] set to TRUE, you also need to get csrf token like this:

```
var post_data = {
    'name': $(this).val(),
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
};

$("#submittodo").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>time.php/checkit',
      type: "POST",
      data: post_data,
      success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI, you need to follow the URL structure, e.g: domain. com/controller/method.c 
In your case:

```
URL : '<?Php echo base_url( ) ?>time/checkit',
```

Mind that there isn't no .Php appended to the controller name. And an absolute URL is used.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 $("#submittodo").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: '<?Php echo base_url(); ?>time/checkit',
          type: "POST",
          data: {name: $(this).val()},
          success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
          }
      });
  });
```